# Cell Style Alignment on a Range

Tags: c#, excel, format, alignment

I'm having a problem formatting cells in an Excel sheet. For some reason my code seems to be changing the style of all cells when I just want to change the style of a few specified, or a specified range.

Here's some of the code that I am using:

```
app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];

//Change all cells' alignment to center
worksheet.Cells.Style.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

//But then this line changes every cell style back to left alignment
worksheet.Cells[y + 1, x + 2].Style.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
```

Why would it change the style of multiple cells when I set it to just work on one? Is it not supposed to work how I want it to? Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Based on this comment from the OP, "I found the problem. apparentlyworksheet.Cells[y + 1, x + 1].HorizontalAlignment", I believe the real explanation is that all the cells start off sharing the same Style object. So if you change that style object, it changes all the cells that use it. But if you just change the cell's alignment property directly, only that cell is affected.

Comment: Yup haha, accidentally submitted that comment before finishing writing it. I guess my attempt to delete it failed. `worksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").Style.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;` would change every cell's allignment. to change just one (or in a range) use `worksheet.Cells[y, x].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;`

Answer (score 40):

This works good

```
worksheet.get_Range("A1","A14").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = 
                 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe declaring a range might workout better for you.

```
// fill in the starting and ending range programmatically this is just an example. 
string startRange = "A1";
string endRange = "A1";
Excel.Range currentRange = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(startRange , endRange );
currentRange.Style.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
```

Comment: Btw if you want to work on a single cell you provide it with the same start and end range. eg:

    Excel.Range currentRange = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(startRange , startRange );

Comment: It's still changing all the cells to have left alignment

Answer (score 3):

Don't use "Style:

```
worksheet.Cells[y,x].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  ExcelApp.Sheets[1].Range[ExcelApp.Sheets[1].Cells[1, 1], ExcelApp.Sheets[1].Cells[70, 15]].Cells.HorizontalAlignment =
                 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
```

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying styles directly in range or cells did not work for me. But the idea to:

1. create a separate style
2. apply all the necessary style property values
3. set the style's name to the `Style` property of the range

, given in [MSDN How to: Programmatically Apply Styles to Ranges in Workbooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1hh9fza.aspx) did the job.

For example:

```
var range = worksheet.Range[string.Format("A{0}:C{0}", rowIndex++)];
range.Merge();
range.Value = "some value";

var style = workbook.AddStyle();
style.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;

range.Style = style.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that works for me. Enjoy.

```
Excel.Application excelApplication =  new Excel.Application()  // start excel and turn off msg boxes
{
     DisplayAlerts = false,
     Visible = false
};

Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(targetFile);
Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets[1];

var rDT = workSheet.Range(workSheet.Cells[monthYearNameRow, monthYearNameCol], workSheet.Cells[monthYearNameRow, maxTableColumnIndex]);
rDT.Merge();
rDT.Value = monthName + " " + year;
var reportDateRowStyle = workBook.Styles.Add("ReportDateRowStyle");
reportDateRowStyle.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
reportDateRowStyle.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
reportDateRowStyle.Font.Bold = true;
reportDateRowStyle.Font.Size = 14;
rDT.Style = reportDateRowStyle;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it works fine..

> ```
> >  worksheet.Range("A4:D4").Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Manikandan's answer is good. For SpreadSheetGear users (a C# framework for interacting easier with spreadsheets) try this:

`workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells["B1:B4"].HorizontalAlignment = HAlign.Center;`.
This will align all the cells in your sheet from B1 to B4 (column 2- row 1 through 4).